# Android UI lags / shutters

Tags: user-interface, lagging

I often see strange/unexpected slowdown in Android UI irrespective of the device I use. UI suddenly skips frames and all graphical transitions seems to run at a very low frame rate (I would say in the range of 10 fps) and with severe lag. After some time it can sometime recover, but not always: the only guaranteed method to return at full speed is to reboot the device.

It seems strange, because:

- it happen on any device I own, but with different absolute effect (ie: on a `Mi A2 Lite` it is *much* more visible than on a `Oneplus 6T` or `Mi 10T Pro`)
- closing all application does not alleviate the slowness/lagging
- when it recover, I did nothing fancy at all (maybe I simply locket/unlocked it).

Comment: The OEMs who are only after UIs to an extent of madness, trying to be unique, ultimately lose in performance. Don't know who tells them that the users only want elegance. Try custom ROMs.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I don't think it is a case of excessive customization: the `Mi A2 Lite` has Android One, which uses the Google launcher (as the Pixel phones). Something similar can be said for the `OnePlus 6T`, which uses a near-stock AOSP launcher.

Comment: I own a Mi A2 Lite. The problem occurred after Android 10 update. Turning off animations in Dev Options seems to give a bit relief. Lag problem is common in Xiaomi devices. What I observed is that their focus is majorly on UI, not on HAL development and resolving hardware/software compatibility issues.

Comment: Not to pass a subjective call but I have owned MiA1, OP7 and this does occasionally happen. I agree with @IrfanLatif that they focus on the "bling value" more and therefore his point